Fatal error: module '' not found when archiving Kotlin Multiplatform project with Pod dependencies
I am currently working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project that includes several Pod dependencies for the iOS part of the app. When I try to archive the project, I encounter the following error for each Pod library:
Fatal error: module "what ever pod name is" not found
However, when I build and run the app normally, everything works as expected, and I do not encounter any issues.
    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "15.3"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "composeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
        pod("GoogleSignIn")
        pod("PurchasesHybridCommon") {
            version = libs.versions.purchases.common.get()
            extraOpts += listOf("-compiler-option", "-fmodules")
        }
    }

Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Checked Podfile: Verified that all Pod dependencies are correctly listed in the Podfile.
Clean and Rebuild: Performed a clean and rebuild of the project
Pod Installation: Ran pod install to ensure all pods are up to date.
Compatibility: Confirmed that my Kotlin/Native, Gradle, and Pod versions are compatible.
Environment:
Kotlin Version: 1.9.23
Xcode Version: 15.4
macOS Version: 14.6.1 Apple M1
Question
Why does this issue occur specifically during the archiving process? Is there a step I might be missing, or a common configuration issue that could lead to these errors? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
